# Is there a way to make ubuntu 22.04 default remote (vnc) to localhost only?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

Is there a way to make default ubuntu 22.04 remote (vnc) to localhost only?

I used ssh + localhost vnc(tiger vnc), but it is handy to implement on each ubuntu.
so I want to use default one.
but I cannot find button to make ubuntu remote(vnc) to allow local only.

Is there a solution for ubuntu default remote(vnc)?
(ubuntu 22.04, ubuntu 20.04)

Additional information:
thanks for reply, My question is : like other vnc server, or like old ubuntu default vnc Vino, does ubuntu20.04 or ubuntu 22.04 vnc has ability to use localhost only option.

Comment: Do not understand the question. You are asking how to make a remote access program local only?

Comment: thanks for reply, My question is : like other vnc server, or like old ubuntu default vnc Vino, does ubuntu20.04 or ubuntu 22.04 vnc has ability to use localhost only option.

Comment: Please add this to the question not just as a comment. It is info for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for it.
use iptables to make tcp port 5900 allow only local packet.

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5900 -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5900 -j DROP`

have a nice day.